# Regex for multiple filename string patterns

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I want to parse certain information from given patterns, which are as follows:

```
/root/test/subfolder/
relative/folder/
index.html
/root/test/style.css
test/test2/test3/testN/
```

I created a regex but it doesn't match multiple strings like root/, test/ only the last instance. My code:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^(/?)([\w\.]+/)*([\w\.]+)?$");

foreach (Group gr in re.Match("/templates/base/test/header.html").Groups)
  Console.WriteLine(gr + " @ " + gr.Index.ToString());

Console.ReadKey();
```

I want to have first slash as optional, then path with / at the end and optional filename at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated capturing groups always capture only the last repetition. But you can capture the entire repeated group instead (and use non-capturing parentheses `(?:...)` for the repeated group:

```
 Regex re = new Regex(@"^(/?)((?:[\w\.]+/)*)([\w\.]+)?$
```

This will work in other regex flavors, too. .NET offers another feature, though: It is possible to [access the individual matches of a repeated capturing group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx). Using your regex:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(/?)([\w\.]+/)*([\w\.]+)?$");
foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[2].Captures) {
    Console.WriteLine("      Capture {0}: {1}", captureCtr, capture.Value);
    captureCtr += 1;                  
}
```

Comment: I want to match only single line from examples above. I just need multiple matches from the middle, like /templates/test/subfolder/test.html then I want it also to match templates/, test/ and subfolder/ in the middle group.

Comment: Ok, I discovered captures in group. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @alexander: Ah, OK, I had misunderstood your question. Edited my answer now.

Comment: One more question, if I have a pattern which is optional (ended with a ? mark) and the part that is important i inside of it after required characters. like (:([\w]+))? i need only [\w]+ but not entire group.